# get_users() timeout on big userbase -- options to divide query?

Tags: users

We run a daily cron that gets **all** the users' data and updates their values. The problem is that [get_users()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) is timing out because of the big userbase. Yes, I can update the `php.ini` file and increase the timeout limit, but it would only delay the inevitable.

So, potential solution is to `get_users()` in batches. For example, on the first batch, we get the users with ID 1-1000. Is the best approach to use the `include` parameter and list 1-1000 IDs in an array? Seems quite desperate.

What other options are there for scenarios like these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track with the batch idea. You'll need a combination of parameters in your get_users() call. A combination of the "number" and "offset" parameters should get you what you need. In the example below $count is a reference to the batch that's currently running.

```
<?php
// inside a loop where $count is the number of times the loop has run
$args = array(
    'number'       => 1000,
    'offset'       => $count * 1000,
);
get_users($args)
?>
```

UPDATE: $count would start at 0.

The first time through the loop you'd get a set of 1000 users starting from the first user in the database because 0 * 1000 = 0 (no offset)

The second time through the loop you'd get another set of 1000 users starting from the 1001st user in the database because 1 * 1000 = 1000 (i.e. skip the first 1000 results and retrieve the next set)

Your loop should continue for as long as you have results being returned.

Comment: Help me understand this. So $count is the number of times the loop as run, so it starts with 1. I understand that part. But exactly which users does it *get* in each batch? For example, I set $count to 1, and the results included users with id 10 and id 5000... as you can understand, I want to ensure that all users will be covered once the batch is finished.

Comment: No problem at all. Good luck with your project.